# Some setting not in XCode 5.1 Build Settings

Tags: xcode, code-signing, xcode5.1

[image: Build Settings]

See the screenshot above, I was looking for **Code Signing** section, but missing when I create a New project from XCode 5.1 *(project created by XCode 5.0 still can see that section)*

Is there anyway to bring out that section?

Comment: You've clicked Basic. Click All instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the filter from "Basic" to "All" in the top left corner.